# How to customize default "Lorem ipsum" snippet in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Default "Lorem ipsum" snippet in Sublime Text 3 is generating a paragraph with line breaks. I installed another lorem snippet from joshnh/HTML-Snippets, but now I have two snippets acting on "lorem"+<tab>. How do I customize/disable/remove default lorem snippet?

Update: installing "Emmet" package did what I want (has overridden the keymap "lorem"+<tab>), but the default snippet is there and I wonder if I could customize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strangely, the *Lorem ipsum* snippet is in the Plain Text package, with scope `-source`, meaning it works everywhere **except** source code files. Since HTML is scope `text.html.basic`, it works there.

To get rid of it in Sublime Text 2, click on **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open the `Packages` folder. Go to the `Text` folder and delete the file `lorem.sublime-snippet`. If you just want to edit it, open the file with XML syntax and have your way with it.

Packages in Sublime Text 3 are by default kept in zipped `.sublime-package` files, so you can't just outright delete the file - instead you'll have to mask it. To completely disable it, open the `Packages` folder as above, and create a folder called `Text` (make sure it's capitalized on case-sensitive file systems). Inside text, create an empty file called `lorem.sublime-snippet`, and you'll be all set. If you want to edit the snippet, its original contents are as follows:

```xml
<snippet>
    <description>Lorem ipsum</description>
    <content><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>lorem</tabTrigger>
    <scope>-source</scope>
</snippet>
```

Alternatively, you can install the excellent [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. It allows you to extract the contents of `.sublime-package` files into the `Packages` folder, or you can view (and edit, if you wish) individual files. Once installed, open the Command Palette and type ***`prv`*** for PackageResourceViewer. There are two options by default: `Extract Package` and `Open Resource`. If you're just editing a single file, choose `Open Resource`, then navigate through the file tree until you find it. If you save changes, PRV will create a new folder in `Packages` with the package's name, and the file inside it. This will override the default package, so be careful when upgrading.

As you found, Emmet has its own version of *Lorem ipsum*, and like most things in Emmet is better than the original - you can customize how much you want, paragraph breaks, repeats, etc. If you haven't found it already, http://emmet.io has all the documentation.

Comment: Question: Is there any plugin that does just this so I don't have to configure this every time?

Comment: @srph Is there any plugin that does just *what*? I'm not sure what you're asking...

Comment: A Lorem Ipsum plugin that simply removed that `source` scope.

Comment: @srph Package Control has [a number](https://packagecontrol.io/search/ipsum) of *Lorem ipsum* related packages.